# Question about using logic within a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a subquery I'm trying to use as a way of pulling a Customer's bill type (Quick Bill or Full Bill) based on the type of bill being used. Currently my code is pulling the most recently confirmed bill type, but I would like to add some logic in to get a desired result.

I would like some logic in place to determine which bill type to show. The hierarchy is I want the Full Bill, if there's no Full Bill then give me QuickBill1 or QuickBill2.

So, if a customer has a Full Bill and a QuickBill1, it will always display the Full Bill. If the customer doesn't have a Full Bill, then QuickBill1 or QuickBill2 can be used.

```
ISNULL((SELECT TOP (1)
    cb.Name
FROM CustomerBilling cb WITH(NOLOCK)
    JOIN BillType bt WITH(NOLOCK)
        ON bt.DiagTypeDimID = cb.DiagTypeDimID                                   
WHERE cb.CustomerEventID = d.CustomerEventID --linking this subquery to the main query
     AND bt.DiagType IN ('FullBillName', 'QuickBill1', 'QuickBill2')
     ORDER BY cb.ConfirmedDtm DESC), '**Bill Unavilable**')  AS 
"BillName"
```

Comment: Why `WITH(NOLOCK)` out of interest?

Comment: Please include some sample data for the two tables (as minimal as possible).  Maybe we can find some way to avoid such an ugly subquery.

Comment: Your comment "--linking this subquery to the main query" makes no sense.  There is no sub query here.

Answer (score 0):

You can split this sub-query into three separate sub-queries and use coalesce instead of isnull. Look for the most important bill type (FullBillName) in the first sub-query, and so forth.

```
COALESCE((SELECT TOP (1)
cb.Name
FROM CustomerBilling cb WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN BillType bt WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON bt.DiagTypeDimID = cb.DiagTypeDimID                                   
WHERE cb.CustomerEventID = d.CustomerEventID --linking this subquery to the main query
 AND bt.DiagType = 'FullBillName'
 ORDER BY cb.ConfirmedDtm DESC), 
(SELECT TOP (1)
cb.Name
FROM CustomerBilling cb WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN BillType bt WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON bt.DiagTypeDimID = cb.DiagTypeDimID                                   
WHERE cb.CustomerEventID = d.CustomerEventID --linking this subquery to the main query
 AND bt.DiagType = 'QuickBill1'
 ORDER BY cb.ConfirmedDtm DESC), 
(SELECT TOP (1)
cb.Name
FROM CustomerBilling cb WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN BillType bt WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON bt.DiagTypeDimID = cb.DiagTypeDimID                                   
WHERE cb.CustomerEventID = d.CustomerEventID --linking this subquery to the main query
 AND bt.DiagType = 'QuickBill2'
 ORDER BY cb.ConfirmedDtm DESC), '**Bill Unavilable**')  AS 
"BillName"
```

or you can define "bill type priority" - a field in BillType table and order by it when selecting the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do it, but without the rest of your query and some sample data, it's hard to know for sure:

```
cb.name,
ISNULL(bt.DiagType, '**Bill Unavilable**') AS BillName

FROM CustomerBilling cb
LEFT JOIN BillType bt
  ON bt.DiagTypeDimID = cb.DiagTypeDimID  
  AND cb.CustomerEventID = d.CustomerEventID --linking this subquery to the main query
WHERE bt.DiagType IN ('FullBillName', 'QuickBill1', 'QuickBill2')
ORDER BY cb.ConfirmedDtm,
    CASE bt.DiagType
        WHEN 'FullBillName' THEN 1
        WHEN 'QuickBill1'   THEN 2
        WHEN 'QuickBill2'   THEN 3
        ELSE 9
    END
```

Comment: You'll need a TOP 1 clause too.

Comment: yeah but I'm trying to avoid the big subquery altogether (I hates' em!)  Need to see the rest of the query

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the prioritization logic in the `ORDER BY`?

```
SELECT TOP (1) cb.Name
FROM CustomerBilling cb JOIN
     BillType bt 
     ON bt.DiagTypeDimID = cb.DiagTypeDimID                                   
WHERE cb.CustomerEventID = d.CustomerEventID --linking this subquery to the main query AND
       bt.DiagType IN ('FullBillName', 'QuickBill1', 'QuickBill2')
ORDER BY (CASE bt.DiagType WHEN 'FullBillName' THEN 1
                           WHEN 'QuickBill1' THEN 2
                           WHEN 'QuickBill2' THEN 3
          END);
```